# Error message on the 'how to find us' page of our website

Tags: google-maps

We have recently set up a web page which has a find us page displaying a google map of our location. However, after a few seconds of being on this page, an error message is displayed saying that we have exceeded our daily quota for maps. I have had a look and it seems there is a limit of 25,000 map loads per day. I am quite certain we do not exceed this amount! How can we rectify this problem?

http://www.forwardarchitecture.co.uk/how-to-find-us/4578515711

Answer (score 0):

Your map is being served by:

```
http://www.map-generator.org/3bc9ceb1-3aab-469a-aa7e-e58ce2d001e3/iframe-map.aspx
```

If you link directly to a google map, and not a shared site, you will have your own quota.